# Tell valgrind to generate suppression statement to a file

Tags: valgrind

valgrind can be run using argument --gen-suppressions=yes (or e.g. --gen-suppressions=all). This helps generate the statements and their syntax to define the contents of a suppression file. That suppression file can be fed into valgrind the next time.
This is for instance useful to suppress those "Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)" messages that are so often reported but not really a problem. I wish there was an easy way for valgrind to just not bother telling me about conditional jump issues, but it appears to be stern about having to tell me about it.

The cumbersome thing is that the output is printed on stdout. I have to then copy-paste those printed statements to the suppression file. Problem is that the program prints a whole lot of stuff to stdout as well.

So, can I tell valgrind to print those suppression statements to a suppression file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect valgrind output to a file use: `--log-file=test.log`. If you find the output is mixed with the application output then redirect valigrind output to separate file descriptor: `--log-fd=9 9>>test.log`.